# How to set 1080i50 in “monitors.xml” on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: screen

I want to set 1080i50 on my HDMI1 output, but I don't find how to set this in "~/.config/monitors.xml", can someone help me ?

I have set "width 1920", "height 1080" and "rate 50" but what is the setting for set "interlace" on ?

I can't use xrandr for it because when I unplug and replug the monitor, he go to 1080p 50Hz but I need to set it in default settings.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I too would like to know how to disable/enable interlacing explicitly.